# How to diagnose a Django registration form that appears to do nothing?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-registration

I'm making a registration system for my django website and this registration form isn't working. I don't know why, I fill out the form and it does nothing. It doesn't redirect to my register_success page. Here is my code so you can help diagnose the issue.

Views.py:

```
def register_user(request):
    if request.method == 'post':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/register_success')

    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    args['form'] = UserCreationForm()
    print(args)
    return render_to_response('register.html', args)


def register_success(request):
    return render_to_response('register_success.html')
```

Register.html:

```
<html>
<body>
{% block content %}
    <h2>Register</h2>
    <form action="/accounts/register/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <input type="submit" value="Register"/>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

Register_success.html:

```
<html>
<body>
{% block content %}
    <h2>You have registered</h2>
    <p>Click <a href="/accounts/login/">here</a> to login.</p>
{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there any error you're getting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are always creating a blank form. This means that you will not see any errors in your form.

```
args['form'] = UserCreationForm()
```

You can fix this by changing your view as follows.

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def register_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/register_success')
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()

    return render(request, 'register.html', {'form': form})
```

Note that the first if statement should be `if request.method == 'POST':`, as spotted by yedpodtrzitko in their answer. I've switched from the deprecated `render_to_response` to `render`, which simplifies things. I recommend you update your success view as well.

```
def register_success(request):
    return render(request, 'register_success.html')
```

Answer (score 2):

The value of `request.method` should be `POST`, not `post` (uppercase vs. lowercase).

I'd recommend you using class-based views, your wont need to write that much code, and it will be more synoptic.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I'm using class-based views on my other views file.